# how to fetch data from one XML group of elements and feed onto another XML group

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, exslt

I am trying to update an element in below XML using data in secondary or different xml file. Both input XML and secondary XML file has equal number of segments. I need to take a value in first segment of secondary XML and update an element in INPUT xml and so on. I am not sure whether it can be done using XSL or not, can anyone guide me.

To be more specific, i am trying to update INPUT XML's `<indicator></indicator>` value in each `<iOSection>` based on secondary XML's //PDetails/PStatus/Code and //PDetails/PStatus/Description values.

Below is INPUT XML file:

```
<IResponse>
    <iOSection>
        <Details>           
            <Info>
                <pNumber>FB061689</pNumber>
                <indicator></indicator>
                <Identifier>1</Identifier>
            </Info>         
        </Details>
        <Token>
            <Reference>1UUYD05BHM21OJCK3881C7F</Reference>
        </Token>
    </iOSection>
    <iOSection>
        <Details>           
            <Info>
                <pNumber>FB061690</pNumber>
                <indicator></indicator>
                <Identifier>2</Identifier>
            </Info>
        </Details>
        <Token>
            <Reference>1UUYD05BHM21OJCK3881C7F</Reference>
        </Token>
    </iOSection>
</IResponse>
```

below is secondary XML file - it is available in xsl variable called RSPDetails

```
<RS PartID="abcd" SysID="mnc">  
    <PDetails>
        <PN>FB063586</PN>
        <PStatus>
            <Code>0</Code>
            <Description>Cancelled</Description>
        </PStatus>     
    </PDetails>
    <PDetails>
        <Error>
            <Code>92</Code>
            <Message>failed</Message>
        </Error>
    </PDetails>
</RS>
```

The value of `<indicator>` should be 'YES' when //PDetails/PStatus/Code = '0' and //PDetails/PStatus/Description = 'Cancelled' , in all other cases it should be 'NO'

The condition should apply for `<iOSection>` position 1 using `<PDetails>` position 1 data and `<iOSection>` position 2 using `<PDetails>` position 2 data and so on

Expecting OUTPUT is:

```
<IResponse>
    <iOSection>
        <Details>           
            <Info>
                <pNumber>FB061689</pNumber>
                <indicator>YES</indicator>
                <Identifier>1</Identifier>
            </Info>         
        </Details>
        <Token>
            <Reference>1UUYD05BHM21OJCK3881C7F</Reference>
        </Token>
    </iOSection>
    <iOSection>
        <Details>           
            <Info>
                <pNumber>FB061690</pNumber>
                <indicator>NO</indicator>
                <Identifier>2</Identifier>
            </Info>
        </Details>
        <Token>
            <Reference>1UUYD05BHM21OJCK3881C7F</Reference>
        </Token>
    </iOSection>
</IResponse>
```

I tried below XSL, but not getting anywhere closer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" >

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()='IResponse']/*[local-name()='iOSection']/*[local-name()='Details']/*[local-name()='Info']/*[local-name()='indicator']">

        <xsl:variable name="RSDetails">
            <RS PartID="abcd" SysID="mnc">
                <PDetails>
                    <PN>FB063586</PN>
                    <PStatus>
                        <Code>0</Code>
                        <Description>Cancelled</Description>
                    </PStatus>
                </PDetails>
                <PDetails>
                    <Error>
                        <Code>92</Code>
                        <Message>failed</Message>
                    </Error>
                </PDetails>
            </RS>       
        </xsl:variable> 

        <xsl:element name="indicator">
            <xsl:variable name="PStatus">
                <xsl:value-of select="$RSDetails/RS/PDetails/PStatus" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="Message">
                <xsl:value-of select="$RSDetails/RS/PDetails/Message" />
            </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$PStatus='0' and $Message='Cancelled'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'YES'" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'NO'" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have tagged this XSLT 2.0, but your stylesheet says version 1.0. Which is it?

Comment: is it possible with xslt2.0?

Comment: The question is still not clear. Is the "secondary file" a real file, or is it hard-coded into your stylesheet, as shown in your example (which would make very little sense)?

Comment: HI Michael, thanks for looking into it. the second file is in a real file which i copied into xsl variable as below  <xsl:variable name="RSDetails"
   select="document('secondary.xml')" />  . so the content is available in variable $RSDetails

Comment: As I said, that makes no sense. You should refer to the external file as `document('yourotherfile.xml')" />`. Also, the structure of the file does not match your description: for example, `RS/PDetails/PStatus` has no value. And  the two `PDetails>` elements have completely different structures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68432/discussion-between-sarma-and-michael-hor257k).

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry for the confusion. if the values in secondary file //PDetails/PStatus/Code = '0' and //PDetails/PStatus/Description = 'Canceled' then indicator value should be YES, otherwise NO. So in second PDetails segment, indicator value becomes NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here is *lookup* a value from a matching node in the external file. You didn't say so, but I presume the matching node is the one where the `PN` value matches the local `pNumber`.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="RSPDetails" select="document('your_other_file.xml')" />
<xsl:key name="rsp" match="PDetails" use="PN" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="indicator">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="pnum" select="../pNumber"/>
        <!-- switch context to the other file -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$RSPDetails">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="key('rsp', $pnum)/PStatus/Code=0 and key('rsp', $pnum)/PStatus/Description='Cancelled'">YES</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>NO</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

To base the lookup on position, try:

```
<xsl:template match="indicator">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="i">
            <xsl:number count="iOSection"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="detail" select="$RSPDetails/RS/PDetails[number($i)]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$detail/PStatus/Code=0 and $detail/PStatus/Description='Cancelled'">YES</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>NO</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The `<xsl:key>` instruction is not necessary in this scenario.

Comment: HI Michael, thanks for looking into it. It is working great when we lookup using PN. It works for me. I am just curious, is it possible to lookup based on position, i mean first occurrence of indicator value should be updated based on first occurrence of PDetails segment, second occurrence of indicator should be updated based on second occurrence of PDetails and so on..